# How to get the times of render with jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

like this:

```
const root = mount(...);
expect(root.render.mock.calls.length).tobe(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionaly to mocking, suggested by @Whj you can just spyOn render.

```
const renderSpy = jest.spyOn(root.instance(), 'render');
root.instance().forceUpdate(); // Needed to bound spy to component's instance
expect(renderSpy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use mock function.

```
root.instance().render = jest.fn(root.instance().render); // Mock Implementations
expect(root.instance().render.mock.calls.length).tobe(1);
```